# SwiftUI set max height on ScrollView

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I have built a Chips Container based on this [link](https://prafullkumar77.medium.com/swiftui-building-chips-with-autolayout-container-dbca53bbb848). Basically is just a container that orders chips in rows. This is my code:

```
struct ChipsContent: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ChipsViewModel()
    @State private var totalHeight
              = CGFloat.zero
    
    var body: some View {
        var width = CGFloat.zero
        var height = CGFloat.zero
        return ScrollView {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading, content: {
                    ForEach(viewModel.dataObject) { chipsData in
                        Chips(systemImage: chipsData.systemImage,
                              titleKey: chipsData.titleKey,
                              isSelected: chipsData.isSelected)
                            .padding(.all, 5)
                            .alignmentGuide(.leading) { dimension in
                                if (abs(width - dimension.width) > geo.size.width) {
                                    width = 0
                                    height -= dimension.height
                                }
                                
                                let result = width
                                if chipsData.id == viewModel.dataObject.last!.id {
                                    width = 0
                                } else {
                                    width -= dimension.width
                                }
                                return result
                              }
                            .alignmentGuide(.top) { dimension in
                                let result = height
                                if chipsData.id == viewModel.dataObject.last!.id {
                                    height = 0
                                }
                                return result
                            }
                    }
                    }).background(viewHeightReader($totalHeight))
            }.padding(.all, 5)
        }.frame(height: height)
    }
    
    private func viewHeightReader(_ binding: Binding<CGFloat>) -> some View {
            return GeometryReader { geometry -> Color in
                let rect = geometry.frame(in: .local)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    binding.wrappedValue = rect.size.height
                }
                return .clear
            }
        }
}
```

With this code, the container gets the height according to its content. I want to set a max-height to the Scroll view and if the content is greater than this max height the content should be scrollable. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.frame(minHeight: …, maxHeight: …)`

By setting minimum and maximum heights you are limiting the freedom of SwiftUI to decide about the size, so you have more control versus just mentioning `.frame(height: …)`, which is treated as a recommendation but not a value that must be adhered to.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/frame(width:height:alignment:)) doesn't really support this notion that `.frame(height: …)`  is treated as a recommendation. Where is that from?

Comment: You are right about the documentation, using .frame(height: …) should mention the fix size. But at least from my experience, it does not work this way. Maybe they will fix it or already did.

Comment: I assume that it tries to respect the fixed size, but like autolayout it will break the sizes if it has to to resolve conflicts.